# Just installed nvim 0.10 and can't find or open it

Tags: fedora, nvim

I installed nvim 0.9 from [this site](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim) but I can't find or open it, if I try to use `sudo dnf install neovim` It says `Package neovim-0.10.0~dev.361.ge3e6fadfd-500.fc36.x86_64 is already installed.` but when I type the `nvim` command it says `zsh: nvim: command not found... Similar command is: 'vim'`. Please what can I do.

Comment: hi! So, the fedora neovim package definitely *does* contain `nvim` (I know because I'm using it). So, are you installing the "official" package, or are you installing the nightly package from COPR?

Comment: Yes, it's from COPR

Comment: then let me have a look at that!

Comment: Oh, you're still using F36!

Comment: Yeah, still on 36 

Comment: Yeah, really not great, that's been end-of-life for four months now. Time to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Pulled up a container with the obsolete F36, installed the copr `neovim` package there.

So, that COPR isn't the greatest: it doesn't declare dependencies on `lua5.1-lpeg`, which you definitely need to run neovim. But with that installed, the `nvim` executable that the COPR-provided RPM ships (`rpm -ql neovim | grep 'bin/nvim$'`) definitely works. So, it's not a problem with the packaging.

If your `zsh` can't find it, you somehow must bent the `PATH` to not include `/usr/bin` (but then *a lot* of things would be broken). This usually shouldn't help, but start a new `zsh` and try from there.